# C++: What does if 0 and asm means in these lines of code?

Tags: c++, if-statement, assembly

```
#if 0
__asm__ ( ".section .init,\"ax\"" );
__asm__ ( "bl InitDevice" );
__asm__ ( "bl ThrMsgManInit" );
__asm__ ( ".section .text" );
#endif
```

Please help me to understand the above lines of code.

Comment: `#if 0` is a C pre processor directive that skips over (doesn't emit) the code between the `#if 0` and `#endif` . Effectively in this case it is like commenting out the code. You could include the code by changing `#if 0` to `#if 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#if 0` is a preprocessor directive.  Everything between the `#if 0` and the matching `#endif` will be ignored by the compiler, because the `#if` expression is 0.  If it were non-zero, then it would not be skipped.

The `__asm__` directive causes the associated text to be placed in the assembler file.  But this will not happen in your example because of the `#if 0`.

Answer (score 1):

`#if 0` is a way to comment things out without risk of nesting problems with `/* */` comments.

It also makes it easy to enable with one edit, rather than also having to edit out the `*/` at the end.

You can hack around that by writing `//   */` on the last line, so when you remove the opening `/*`, the closing `*/` will be inside a `//` comment instead of being a syntax error.

```
/*
  statement; //  but no C-style comments
  statement2;
//  */
```

Remove the opening `/*` or add a `*/` on the same line to enable the statement;